# How to send large amount of data to servlet

Tags: android, tomcat, servlets

I'm writing an Android app, which has a function to upload data to a servlet, and when I say data I mean a lot of strings. The servlet is running in Apache Tomcat v6, and written in Java. Everywhere I look I see that one way of doing this is by using `HttpUrlConnection`.

Client side:

```
URL u = new URL("http://servlet location");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setDoInput(true);
httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
httpCon.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(httpCon.getInputStream()); // line 8
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(httpCon.getOutputStream());
// -- writing to servlet using the outputStream --`
... ...
```

Servlet side:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
int numFiles = dis.readInt(); //line 3
for(int i=0;i<numFiles;i++)
{
    this.data.add(dis.readUTF()); //data is a vector that contains String types
}
```

When I get to line 8 on the client side, it fires a `HTTP GET` request, that preforms the servlet side.

All is good, but when the servlet comes to the `ois.readUTF()` it's throwing me an exception, instead of waiting for incoming data.

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: in the servlet i get an EOF exception

Answer (score 0):

When you have large amount of data, like a big file or a big image/good quality image to send to server, then you can send it in parts/chunks.

First make an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) connection with the server and then send chunks with the `DataOutputStream` Class. On the server side same, you need to implement code for receiving these chunks and make them in one file once you get all the chunks.

Comment: this is what i'm trying to do, but its not working.
when the servlet comes to the line ois.readUTF() it throws me an exception instead of waiting for data...

Comment: the servlet throws an java.io.EOFException when it gets to line 3 in the servlet.
p.s - i want to upload strings, not files...